# How to get motherboard slots information .NET

Tags: .net

I want to get the information of the motherboard like the RAM(manufacturer, capacity .etc.), Slots(PCI, PCI-E), I tried to use WMI but it can't returns all the information, anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score -1):

its easy though, Open your cmd as administrator and type :

```
wmic cpu
```

for cpu info

```
wmic baseboard
```

for motherboard info

Comment: How can I get the slots information, for the baseboard it doesn't tell me the slot information.